# Angular i18n to generic form from array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I have a form that is created from an object I received from the API. To create this form I created an array of objects on the TS and then I make the loop and add the inputs/selects. The form is rendered correctly, but when I translate the application, this form doesn't is translated.

```
import { SpecializedAreasComponents } from 'src/app/models/SpecializedAreasComponent';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'citation-constraint-form',
 templateUrl: './citation-constraint-form.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./citation-constraint-form.component.scss'],
})
export class CitationConstraintFormComponent implements SpecializedAreasComponents, OnInit {
 form: FormGroup;
 @Input() data: any;
 @Output() output: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 @Input() errors: any = {};
 @Input() allowEdit;
 constraints: any = [];
 selectOne = [
     {
         value: '',
         description: 'Select One...',
     },
 ];
 bool = [
     ...this.selectOne,
     {
         description: 'Yes',
         value: true,
     },
     {
         description: 'No',
         value: false,
     },
 ];
 activitySectors = [
     ...this.selectOne,
     {
         value: 'industry',
         description: 'Industry',
     },
     {
         value: 'wholesale',
         description: 'Wholesale',
     },
     {
         value: 'retail',
         description: 'Retail',
     },
     {
         value: 'finalConsumer',
         description: 'Final Consumer',
     },
     {
         value: 'service',
         description: 'Service',
     },
     {
         value: 'ruralProducer',
         description: 'Rural Producer',
     },
     {
         value: 'generalWarehouse',
         description: 'General Warehouse',
     },
     {
         value: 'stockWarehouse',
         description: 'Stock Warehouse',
     },
     {
         value: 'transporter',
         description: 'Transporter',
     },
     {
         value: 'publicAgency',
         description: 'Public Agency',
     },
     {
         value: 'telco',
         description: 'Communication Service',
     },
     {
         value: 'importer',
         description: 'Importer',
     },
     {
         value: 'mealSupplier',
         description: 'Meal Supplier',
     },
     {
         value: 'coops',
         description: 'Cooperative',
     },
     {
         value: 'farmCoop',
         description: 'Farms Cooperative',
     },
     {
         value: 'transporter',
         description: 'Transporter',
     },
     {
         value: 'distributionCenter',
         description: 'Distribution Center',
     },
     {
         value: 'electricityDistributor',
         description: 'Electricity Distributor',
     },
     {
         value: 'fuelDistributor',
         description: 'Fuel Distributor',
     },
     {
         value: 'pharmaDistributor',
         description: 'Medication Distributor',
     },
     {
         value: 'waterDistributor',
         description: 'Water Dispenser',
     },
     {
         value: 'publicAgency',
         description: 'Orgao Publico',
     },
     {
         value: 'religiousEstablishment',
         description: 'Temples of Any Worship',
     },
     {
         value: 'itaipubiNacional',
         description: 'Itaipu Binacional',
     },
     {
         value: 'auctioneer',
         description: 'Auctioneer',
     },
 ];
 federalTaxRegimes = [
     {
         value: 'realProfit',
         description: 'Real profit',
     },
     {
         value: 'estimatedProfit',
         description: 'Estimated profit',
     },
     {
         value: 'simplified',
         description: 'Simplified',
     },
     {
         value: 'simplifiedOverGrossthreshold',
         description: 'Simplified over grossthreshold',
     },
     {
         value: 'simplifiedEntrepreneur',
         description: 'Simplified entrepreneur',
     },
     {
         value: 'notApplicable',
         description: 'Not applicable',
     },
     {
         value: 'individual',
         description: 'Individual',
     },
 ];
 entityTypes = [
     {
         value: 'business',
         description: 'Business',
     },
     {
         value: 'individual',
         description: 'Individual',
     },
     {
         value: 'federalGovernment',
         description: 'Federal government',
     },
     {
         value: 'stateGovernment',
         description: 'State government',
     },
     {
         value: 'cityGovernment',
         description: 'City government',
     },
     {
         value: 'foreign',
         description: 'Foreign',
     },
 ];
 specialProductClasses = [
     ...this.selectOne,
     {
         value: '1',
         description: 'SUS',
     },
     {
         value: '2',
         description: 'Órgão do Poder Executivo',
     },
     {
         value: '3',
         description: 'Bancos',
     },
     {
         value: '4',
         description: 'Comércio/Indústria',
     },
     {
         value: '5',
         description: 'Poder Legislativo/Judiciário',
     },
     {
         value: '0',
         description: 'Outro',
     },
 ];
 fiscalTypes = [
     ...this.selectOne,
     {
         value: 'FOR PRODUCT',
         description: 'For product',
     },
     {
         value: 'FOR MERCHANDISE',
         description: 'For merchandise',
     },
     {
         value: 'NO RESTRICTION',
         description: 'No restriction',
     },
     {
         value: 'SERVICE',
         description: 'Service',
     },
     {
         value: 'FEEDSTOCK',
         description: 'Feedstock',
     },
     {
         value: 'FIXED ASSETS',
         description: 'Fixed assets',
     },
     {
         value: 'PACKAGING',
         description: 'Packaging',
     },
     {
         value: 'PRODUCT IN PROCESS',
         description: 'Product in process',
     },
     {
         value: 'SUBPRODUCT',
         description: 'Subproduct',
     },
     {
         value: 'INTERMEDIATE PRODUCT',
         description: 'Intermediate product',
     },
     {
         value: 'MATERIAL FOR USAGE AND CONSUMPTION',
         description: 'Material for usage and consumption',
     },
     {
         value: 'OTHER INPUTS',
         description: 'Other inputs',
     },
 ];
 constraintsTypes = [
     {
         key: 'item',
         label: 'Item',
         type: 'text',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'unit',
         label: 'UNIT',
         type: 'text',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'lowerLimitAmount',
         label: 'Lower Limit Amount',
         type: 'number',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'upperLimitAmout',
         label: 'Upper Limit Amount',
         type: 'number',
     },
     {
         key: 'fiscalType',
         label: 'Fiscal Type',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.fiscalTypes],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'activitySectorListEmmiter',
         label: 'Activity Sector List Emmiter',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.activitySectors],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'activitySectorListReceiver',
         label: 'Activity Sector List Receiver',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.activitySectors],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'packaging',
         label: 'Packaging',
         type: 'text',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'supplementaryInformation',
         label: 'Supplementary Information',
         type: 'text',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'specialProductClass',
         label: 'Special Product Class',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.specialProductClasses],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'ceanTax',
         label: 'CEAN Taxable',
         type: 'text',
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'icmsTaxPayer',
         label: 'ICMS Tax Payer',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.bool],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'subjectPayrollTaxRelief',
         label: 'Subject to Payroll Tax Relief',
         type: 'select',
         options: [...this.bool],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'federalTaxRegimeListReceiver',
         label: 'Federal Tax Regime',
         type: 'multiple',
         options: [...this.federalTaxRegimes],
         ignore: false,
     },
     {
         key: 'entityTypeListReceiver',
         label: 'Entity Type',
         type: 'multiple',
         options: [...this.entityTypes],
         ignore: false,
     },
 ];
 rows = [];

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
         constraint: new FormGroup({
             item: new FormControl(''),
             unit: new FormControl(''),
             lowerLimitAmount: new FormControl(''),
             upperLimitAmout: new FormControl(''),
             fiscalType: new FormControl(''),
             activitySectorListEmmiter: new FormControl(''),
             activitySectorListReceiver: new FormControl(''),
             packaging: new FormControl(''),
             supplementaryInformation: new FormControl(''),
             specialProductClass: new FormControl(''),
             ceanTax: new FormControl(''),
             icmsTaxPayer: new FormControl(''),
             subjectPayrollTaxRelief: new FormControl(''),
             federalTaxRegimeListReceiver: new FormControl([]),
             entityTypeListReceiver: new FormControl([]),
         }),
     });
 }

 getDescFromKey(key) {
     return (
         {
             unit: 'UNIT',
             lowerLimitAmount: 'Lower Limit Amount',
             upperLimitAmount: 'Upper Limit Amount',
             fiscalType: 'Fiscal Type',
             activitySectorListEmmiter: 'Activity Sector List Emmiter',
             activitySectorListReceiver: 'Activity Sector List Receiver',
             packaging: 'Packaging',
             supplementaryInformation: 'Supplementary Information',
             specialProductClass: 'Special Product Class',
             ceanTax: 'CEAN Taxable',
             icmsTaxPayer: 'ICMS Tax Player',
             subjectPayrollTaxRelief: 'Subject to Payroll Tax Relief',
             federalTaxRegimeListReceiver: 'Federal Tax Regime',
             entityTypeListReceiver: 'Entity Type',
         }[key] || key
     );
 }

 updateForm(value) {
     if (
         value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver &&
         value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver[0]?.value &&
         !value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver[0]?.description
     ) {
         value.constraint.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver = value.constraint.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver.map((ftr) => {
             return {
                 value: ftr.value,
                 description: this.getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(ftr.value, 'federalTaxRegimeListReceiver'),
             };
         });
     }
     if (
         value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver &&
         value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver[0]?.value &&
         !value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver[0]?.description
     ) {
         value.constraint.entityTypeListReceiver = value.constraint.entityTypeListReceiver.map((ftr) => {
             return {
                 value: ftr.value,
                 description: this.getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(ftr.value, 'entityTypeListReceiver'),
             };
         });
     }
     this.form.patchValue(this.allowEdit ? value : { constraint: value });
 }

 getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(value, type) {
     const list = type === 'entityTypeListReceiver' ? this.entityTypes : this.federalTaxRegimes;

     const option = list.find((o) => o.value === value);

     return option.description || '';
 }

 ngOnInit() {
     if (!this.allowEdit) this.form.disable();
     this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.output.emit(this.form.value));
     this.updateForm(this.data.constraint);
     this.constraintsTypes.map((constraint, i) => {
         const constr = {
             key: constraint.key,
             label: constraint.label,
             value: constraint.type === 'multiple' ? [] : '',
             type: constraint.type,
             options: constraint?.options || [],
         };

         if (i === 0) {
             this.rows.push([constr]);
         } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
             this.rows.push([constr]);
         } else {
             this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].push(constr);
         }
     });
 }

 extractArray(item) {
     if (Array.isArray(item)) {
         return item.map((a) => (typeof a === 'string' ? a : a.code));
     }

     return item;
 }
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <s-row class="pad-all-none" *ngFor="let row of rows" formGroupName="constraint">
    <s-col span="4" *ngFor="let const of row">
      <fieldset>
        <label [for]="const.key" i18n>{{ const.label }}</label>
        <input
          [type]="const.type"
          [placeholder]="const.label"
          [formControlName]="const.key"
          [id]="const.key"
          *ngIf="const.type === 'text' || const.type === 'number'"
          [attr.disabled]="!allowEdit ? '' : null"
        />
        <select
          [id]="const.key"
          [formControlName]="const.key"
          *ngIf="const.type === 'select'"
          [attr.disabled]="!allowEdit ? '' : null"
        >
          <option *ngFor="let option of const.options" value="{{ option?.value }}">
            {{ option.description }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <kendo-multiselect
          [data]="const.options"
          [textField]="'description'"
          [valueField]="'value'"
          [id]="const.key"
          [formControlName]="const.key"
          [filterable]="true"
          [placeholder]="'Select Multiple'"
          *ngIf="const.type === 'multiple'"
          [attr.disabled]="!allowEdit ? '' : null"
        >
        </kendo-multiselect>
      </fieldset>
    </s-col>
  </s-row>
</form>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can use the i18n here?

Thank you.
Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the global variable `$localize`

My code result was:

```
import { SpecializedAreasComponents } from 'src/app/models/SpecializedAreasComponent';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'citation-constraint-form',
    templateUrl: './citation-constraint-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./citation-constraint-form.component.scss'],
})
export class CitationConstraintFormComponent implements SpecializedAreasComponents, OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    @Input() data: any;
    @Output() output: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() errors: any = {};
    @Input() allowEdit;
    constraints: any = [];

    selectOne = [
        {
            value: '',
            description: $localize`Select One...`,
        },
    ];
    bool = [
        ...this.selectOne,
        {
            description: $localize`Yes`,
            value: true,
        },
        {
            description: $localize`No`,
            value: false,
        },
    ];
    activitySectors = [
        ...this.selectOne,
        {
            value: 'industry',
            description: $localize`Industry`,
        },
        {
            value: 'wholesale',
            description: $localize`Wholesale`,
        },
        {
            value: 'retail',
            description: $localize`Retail`,
        },
        {
            value: 'finalConsumer',
            description: $localize`Final Consumer`,
        },
        {
            value: 'service',
            description: $localize`Service`,
        },
        {
            value: 'ruralProducer',
            description: $localize`Rural Producer`,
        },
        {
            value: 'generalWarehouse',
            description: $localize`General Warehouse`,
        },
        {
            value: 'stockWarehouse',
            description: $localize`Stock Warehouse`,
        },
        {
            value: 'transporter',
            description: $localize`Transporter`,
        },
        {
            value: 'publicAgency',
            description: $localize`Public Agency`,
        },
        {
            value: 'telco',
            description: $localize`Communication Service`,
        },
        {
            value: 'importer',
            description: $localize`Importer`,
        },
        {
            value: 'mealSupplier',
            description: $localize`Meal Supplier`,
        },
        {
            value: 'coops',
            description: $localize`Cooperative`,
        },
        {
            value: 'farmCoop',
            description: $localize`Farms Cooperative`,
        },
        {
            value: 'transporter',
            description: $localize`Transporter`,
        },
        {
            value: 'distributionCenter',
            description: $localize`Distribution Center`,
        },
        {
            value: 'electricityDistributor',
            description: $localize`Electricity Distributor`,
        },
        {
            value: 'fuelDistributor',
            description: $localize`Fuel Distributor`,
        },
        {
            value: 'pharmaDistributor',
            description: $localize`Medication Distributor`,
        },
        {
            value: 'waterDistributor',
            description: $localize`Water Dispenser`,
        },
        {
            value: 'publicAgency',
            description: $localize`Orgao Publico`,
        },
        {
            value: 'religiousEstablishment',
            description: $localize`Temples of Any Worship`,
        },
        {
            value: 'itaipubiNacional',
            description: $localize`Itaipu Binacional`,
        },
        {
            value: 'auctioneer',
            description: $localize`Auctioneer`,
        },
    ];
    federalTaxRegimes = [
        {
            value: 'realProfit',
            description: $localize`Real profit`,
        },
        {
            value: 'estimatedProfit',
            description: $localize`Estimated profit`,
        },
        {
            value: 'simplified',
            description: $localize`Simplified`,
        },
        {
            value: 'simplifiedOverGrossthreshold',
            description: $localize`Simplified over grossthreshold`,
        },
        {
            value: 'simplifiedEntrepreneur',
            description: $localize`Simplified entrepreneur`,
        },
        {
            value: 'notApplicable',
            description: $localize`Not applicable`,
        },
        {
            value: 'individual',
            description: $localize`Individual`,
        },
    ];
    entityTypes = [
        {
            value: 'business',
            description: $localize`Business`,
        },
        {
            value: 'individual',
            description: $localize`Individual`,
        },
        {
            value: 'federalGovernment',
            description: $localize`Federal government`,
        },
        {
            value: 'stateGovernment',
            description: $localize`State government`,
        },
        {
            value: 'cityGovernment',
            description: $localize`City government`,
        },
        {
            value: 'foreign',
            description: $localize`Foreign`,
        },
    ];
    specialProductClasses = [
        ...this.selectOne,
        {
            value: '1',
            description: $localize`SUS`,
        },
        {
            value: '2',
            description: $localize`Órgão do Poder Executivo`,
        },
        {
            value: '3',
            description: $localize`Bancos`,
        },
        {
            value: '4',
            description: $localize`Comércio/Indústria`,
        },
        {
            value: '5',
            description: $localize`Poder Legislativo/Judiciário`,
        },
        {
            value: '0',
            description: $localize`Outro`,
        },
    ];
    fiscalTypes = [
        ...this.selectOne,
        {
            value: 'FOR PRODUCT',
            description: $localize`For product`,
        },
        {
            value: 'FOR MERCHANDISE',
            description: $localize`For merchandise`,
        },
        {
            value: 'NO RESTRICTION',
            description: $localize`No restriction`,
        },
        {
            value: 'SERVICE',
            description: $localize`Service`,
        },
        {
            value: 'FEEDSTOCK',
            description: $localize`Feedstock`,
        },
        {
            value: 'FIXED ASSETS',
            description: $localize`Fixed assets`,
        },
        {
            value: 'PACKAGING',
            description: $localize`Packaging`,
        },
        {
            value: 'PRODUCT IN PROCESS',
            description: $localize`Product in process`,
        },
        {
            value: 'SUBPRODUCT',
            description: $localize`Subproduct`,
        },
        {
            value: 'INTERMEDIATE PRODUCT',
            description: $localize`Intermediate product`,
        },
        {
            value: 'MATERIAL FOR USAGE AND CONSUMPTION',
            description: $localize`Material for usage and consumption`,
        },
        {
            value: 'OTHER INPUTS',
            description: $localize`Other inputs`,
        },
    ];
    constraintsTypes = [
        {
            key: 'item',
            label: $localize`Item`,
            type: 'text',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'unit',
            label: $localize`UNIT`,
            type: 'text',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'lowerLimitAmount',
            label: $localize`Lower Limit Amount`,
            type: 'number',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'upperLimitAmout',
            label: $localize`Upper Limit Amount`,
            type: 'number',
        },
        {
            key: 'fiscalType',
            label: $localize`Fiscal Type`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.fiscalTypes],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'activitySectorListEmmiter',
            label: $localize`Activity Sector List Emmiter`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.activitySectors],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'activitySectorListReceiver',
            label: $localize`Activity Sector List Receiver`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.activitySectors],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'packaging',
            label: $localize`Packaging`,
            type: 'text',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'supplementaryInformation',
            label: $localize`Supplementary Information`,
            type: 'text',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'specialProductClass',
            label: $localize`Special Product Class`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.specialProductClasses],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'ceanTax',
            label: $localize`CEAN Taxable`,
            type: 'text',
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'icmsTaxPayer',
            label: $localize`ICMS Tax Payer`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.bool],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'subjectPayrollTaxRelief',
            label: $localize`Subject to Payroll Tax Relief`,
            type: 'select',
            options: [...this.bool],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'federalTaxRegimeListReceiver',
            label: $localize`Federal Tax Regime`,
            type: 'multiple',
            options: [...this.federalTaxRegimes],
            ignore: false,
        },
        {
            key: 'entityTypeListReceiver',
            label: $localize`Entity Type`,
            type: 'multiple',
            options: [...this.entityTypes],
            ignore: false,
        },
    ];
    rows = [];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            constraint: new FormGroup({
                item: new FormControl(''),
                unit: new FormControl(''),
                lowerLimitAmount: new FormControl(''),
                upperLimitAmout: new FormControl(''),
                fiscalType: new FormControl(''),
                activitySectorListEmmiter: new FormControl(''),
                activitySectorListReceiver: new FormControl(''),
                packaging: new FormControl(''),
                supplementaryInformation: new FormControl(''),
                specialProductClass: new FormControl(''),
                ceanTax: new FormControl(''),
                icmsTaxPayer: new FormControl(''),
                subjectPayrollTaxRelief: new FormControl(''),
                federalTaxRegimeListReceiver: new FormControl([]),
                entityTypeListReceiver: new FormControl([]),
            }),
        });
    }

    getDescFromKey(key) {
        return (
            {
                unit: $localize`UNIT`,
                lowerLimitAmount: $localize`Lower Limit Amount`,
                upperLimitAmount: $localize`Upper Limit Amount`,
                fiscalType: $localize`Fiscal Type`,
                activitySectorListEmmiter: $localize`Activity Sector List Emmiter`,
                activitySectorListReceiver: $localize`Activity Sector List Receiver`,
                packaging: $localize`Packaging`,
                supplementaryInformation: $localize`Supplementary Information`,
                specialProductClass: 'Special Product Class',
                ceanTax: $localize`CEAN Taxable`,
                icmsTaxPayer: $localize`ICMS Tax Player`,
                subjectPayrollTaxRelief: $localize`Subject to Payroll Tax Relief`,
                federalTaxRegimeListReceiver: $localize`Federal Tax Regime`,
                entityTypeListReceiver: $localize`Entity Type`,
            }[key] || key
        );
    }

    updateForm(value) {
        if (
            value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver &&
            value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver[0]?.value &&
            !value?.constraint?.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver[0]?.description
        ) {
            value.constraint.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver = value.constraint.federalTaxRegimeListReceiver.map((ftr) => {
                return {
                    value: ftr.value,
                    description: this.getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(ftr.value, 'federalTaxRegimeListReceiver'),
                };
            });
        }
        if (
            value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver &&
            value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver[0]?.value &&
            !value?.constraint?.entityTypeListReceiver[0]?.description
        ) {
            value.constraint.entityTypeListReceiver = value.constraint.entityTypeListReceiver.map((ftr) => {
                return {
                    value: ftr.value,
                    description: this.getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(ftr.value, 'entityTypeListReceiver'),
                };
            });
        }
        this.form.patchValue(this.allowEdit ? value : { constraint: value });
    }

    getDescriptionForConstraintsTypes(value, type) {
        const list = type === 'entityTypeListReceiver' ? this.entityTypes : this.federalTaxRegimes;

        const option = list.find((o) => o.value === value);

        return option.description || '';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.allowEdit) this.form.disable();
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.output.emit(this.form.value));
        this.updateForm(this.data.constraint);
        this.constraintsTypes.map((constraint, i) => {
            const constr = {
                key: constraint.key,
                label: constraint.label,
                value: constraint.type === 'multiple' ? [] : '',
                type: constraint.type,
                options: constraint?.options || [],
            };

            if (i === 0) {
                this.rows.push([constr]);
            } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
                this.rows.push([constr]);
            } else {
                this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].push(constr);
            }
        });
    }

    extractArray(item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            return item.map((a) => (typeof a === 'string' ? a : a.code));
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```